# Python Sockets: Image is cropped after transferring from client side to server side

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

I have a sever.py file which runs in a while loop:

```
# SNIPPET
def receive_data(client_socket):
    img_id = random.randint(1, 10000)
    try:
        file = open(f'server_image_{img_id}.jpg', "wb")
        image_chunk = client_socket.recv(2048)

        while image_chunk:
            file.write(image_chunk)
            image_chunk = client_socket.recv(2048)

        file.close()
    except:
        return False
while True:
    read_sockets, _, exception_sockets= select.select(sockets_list, [], sockets_list)

    for notified_socket in read_sockets:
        if notified_socket == server_socket:
            client_socket, client_address= server_socket.accept()

            cli_data = receive_data(client_socket)
            if cli_data is False:
                continue
```

and main.py, which has threads running in the background:

```
# SNIPPET
img = open(img_param_path, 'rb')
image_data = img.read(2048)
while image_data:
    client_inst.send(image_data)
    image_data = img.read(2048)

img.close()
```

and this is the output:
[image: left image is the received image, right one is the original image]

Note that I've tried several other images, and they seem to have the same problem too but it is barely noticeable, only this image is about 138kb. I have no idea if the problem is the size or the wrong code. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You are assuming that `send` will always send everything. This assumption is wrong. Check the return value to what was actually send or use `sendall`

Comment: ok so your suggestion kind of worked, but i don't get why the image takes 5 minutes to transfer. Do i need to increase the buffer value? And also after immediately sending, the picture was only one third of the original one and it has gray/purple shades. Socket programming isn't my bread and butter, so I apologize if it sounds stupid

Comment: These are both different questions than the original one. I cannot see anything in the code you show why it should take that long, so maybe it is something outside of the code. The gray/purple shades are simply artefacts of the image not transferred fully yet. It might be better to focus on the actual bytes transferred and not how it looks as an image, i.e. focus on size and byte content are exactly the same.

Comment: i'll explain with more detail: right after i send the image, no matter if its sendall or send, i would get disconnected from the server. Meanwhile the transferred image's size gradually goes up (i.e 0kb, 83kb, and finally 138kb) at which i can see more of the image's content. Actually, the goal that I am going for is that a client can send an image to another client, so i don't think this is even the correct way to do it. Thanks for your suggestion though